# find and replace specific character in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How to find and replace all line who have number with new.

ex

I have

```
visible
visible
2.00707E+13
visible
visible
visible
2.00723E+13
visible
1.00723E+13
visible
visible
2.06407E+13
```

I want to all line who have 13 changing with "deleted" word.

Comment: CTRL+H is search and replace on Notepad++ I believe.

Comment: All lines have different number. All have just same 13. I want to find 13, but replace whole line

Answer (score 1):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `^.*13\R`
- **Replace With:** (Nothing)
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All

The pattern matches lines that have a `13` followed be a linebreak (`\R`) and the whole line (from the start `^` including everything (`.*` , `13` and the linebreak)) is replaced with nothing, thus deleted.